# Angular binding is not working on textbox?

Tags: angularjs

I am facing a string problem. I have placed a text input control and bind it with **controller** property and added a button input, but when i am trying to get the text input value on button click i am getting blank.

Controller

```
chat.controller('chatController', ['$scope', 'board', '$log', function ($scope, board, $log) {
$scope.Messages = [];
$scope.comment = '';
board.startBoard(function () {
    board.loadAllMessages().then(function (messages) {
        $scope.Messages = messages;
    });
});
$scope.likeClick = function (isfromChild, message) {
    $log.info(message);
};
$scope.dislikeClick = function (isfromChild, message) {
    $log.info(message);
};
$scope.addComment = function () {
    //HERE IS THIS PROBLEM
    alert($scope.comment);
    $scope.comment = ''; 
};
} ]);
```

Mark Up

```
 <div style="margin-top: 10px">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="comment" placeholder="write a comment..." />
                                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" data-ng-click="addComment()" id="button1">
                                                Post Commant</button></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `ng-controller` attribute , like this:

```
 <div style="margin-top: 10px"  ng-controller="chatController">
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/shPwB/1/

Comment: @Ravi May be show us more of your code here or you can update my fiddle with your code

Comment: I will show you my code as i am using some SignalR code to get data from server so may be service part will not work.

Comment: @Ravi change this: `$scope.comment` like this: `$scope.data.comment` and it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/shPwB/4/

Comment: @Ravi take a look at Egghead' bindings explanation: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lx7ycjC8qjE

Answer (score 0):

please update it as below

```
 <div style="margin-top: 10px" ng-controller="chatController">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="comment" placeholder="write a comment..." />
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-info" data-ng-click="addComment()" id="button1">
                                            Post Commant</button></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: copy+pasted from my fiddle? :D

Comment: already defined `data-ng-controller='chatController'` at the top container.